# SAPUI5 does not fire events in element binding

Tags: events, binding, element, sapui5

my element binding does not fires a dataReceived event.
What's the matter?

```
this.getView().byId("objectHeader").bindElement(
                "/EntitySet(company='"+ id+"',name='"+ name+"')", {
                    events: {
                        dataReceived: function(rData){
                            console.log("test");
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
```

With 'attachDataReceived' it also does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your parameter construction is not formulated according to what's specified in the [bindElement method](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Element.html#bindElement) description in the SDK. Try to replace your code with the snippet below:

```
this.getView().byId("objectHeader").bindElement({
    path: "/EntitySet(company='" + id + "',name='" + name + "')", 
    events: {
        dataReceived: function(rData) {
            console.log("test");
        }
    }
});
```

Also, you may want to use ODataModel.createKey to create your path (`/EntitySet(company='" + id + "',name='" + name + "')`). Using createKey makes your code cleaner and less dependent on what the OData metamodel looks like.